# Не могу получить тело пост запроса

Tags: node.js, post

Пытаясь получить тело POST запроса назад возвращается `undefined`. POST запрос отправлял через терминал:

```bash
curl -d test=Test -H Accept:application/json --url localhost:3000
```

Страница index возвращается нормально.

Код:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'static'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {});
})
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body); // undefined
  res.render('index', {}); // index прекрасно возвращается пользователю
})

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Port: ${port}`);
})
```

Comment: Попробуй добавить `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))` и `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: Сам запрос пробуй отправить вот так `curl -d "test=Test" -H "Accept:application/json" --url localhost:3000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуй сам запрос отправлять таким образом

```
curl -d "test=Test" -H "Accept:application/json" --url localhost:3000
```

У нас работает вот с такими "добавками".

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'static'));

// Дополнительно добавить
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })) 
app.use(express.json())
//

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {});
})
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.render('index', {});
})

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Port: ${port}`);
})
```